# Proof: Circle-bounded and Square-bounded Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

A set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is called *circle-bounded* if it is contained in a circle centered at the origin. A set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is called *square-bounded* if it is contained in a square centered at the origin and with the sides parallel to the $x$ and $y$-axes.

Prove or Disprove: A set $S$ is circle-bounded if and only if it is square-bounded.

---

I think this claim is true, and I want to prove it. I will have to prove the two following claims in order to prove the statement:

$P$: If a set is circle bounded, then it is also square bounded.

$Q$: If a set is square bounded, then it is also circle bounded.

My strategy would be to say that by definition, if a set is circle bounded, then it is contained in a circle with radius $r$. Then it is also contained in a square with side-length $2r$. If a set is square-bounded, then it is contained in a square with diagonal length $d$. Then it is also contained in a circle with diameter $d$.

---

Is this correct? Is there a better/more efficient way to prove this?

Any help would be appreciated.